# SSRS: Y-axis minimum INTERVAL (not minimum value)

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a column chart in a paginated report. Data is typically in the -0.5% to +0.5% range. I want the number format of the  y-axis labels to be 0.0% (i.e. 1 decimal). When I set the interval to Auto, I get a y axis that goes 0, 0.1%, 0.1%, 0.2%, 0.2%, 0.3%, 0.3%, etc. I know this is because it's showing 1 decimal but is incrementing by 0.05%. Without changing the number format to 0.00%, I'd like to set a minimum for the INTERVAL using an expression. So that the y-axis interval is still mostly auto, but will never be less than 0.1%. So given the same data, I would have half the number of major tickmarks, and it would go 0%, 0.1%, 0.2%, 0.3%, etc. If my data had higher numbers, I want it to set a higher interval automatically, just never let the interval go below 0.1%.

My googling seems to only result in how to set a minimum for the axis, as opposed to a minimum for the INTERVAL. Tried to set the interval for the y-axis as an expression, but don't know what logical test to use for an IIF statement. My dumb way to try (which I know would be incorrect syntax) was simply: Interval: >0.001.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this...

```
=IIF(Max(Fields!myValue.Value, "DataSet1") > .05, "Auto", 0.01)
```

You might want to include a check on both the max and min values, but the above simply checks the largest `myValue` in the entire dataset `"DataSet1"` and if it's above 0.05 (5%) then it will use Automatic intervals but if it's <=0.05 then the interval is forced to 0.01 (1%).

Comment: appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. This answers your question, please mark it as accepted (the check mark to the left under the vote up/down buttons). This helps others find similar answered question.